# Function to produce a single metric to compare the shape of two distributions (predictions vs actuals)

Tags: r, machine-learning, distribution, r-caret

I am assessing the accuracy of a model that predicts count data.

My actual data has quite an unusual distribution - although I have a large amount of data, the shape is unlike any standard distributions (poisson, normal, negative binomial etc.).

As part of my assessment, I want a metric for how well the distribution of the predictions match the distribution of actual data. I've tried using standard model performance metrics, such as MAE or RMSE, but they don't seem to capture how well the predictions match the expected distribution.

My initial idea was to split the predictions into deciles, and calculate what proportion fall in each decile. This would be a very rough indication of the underlying distribution. I would then calculate the same for my 'actuals' and sum the absolute differences between the proportions.

This works to some extent, but feels a bit clunky, and the split into deciles feels arbitrary.  Is there a function in R to produce a single metric for how well two distributions match?

Comment: Have you looked at Kolmogorov-Smirnov distance? It is asymmetric, which shouldn't be a problem since you have one reference distribution and one observed. If you prefer a symmetric comparison, go for Jensen-Shannon.

Comment: @PierreGramme Thanks. I've heard of the Kolmogorov-Smirnov test, but didn't know there was a distance associated with it. I'll look into that.

Comment: Anderson–Darling test as well, Shapiro-Wilks for normals